# Java: What happens when you try to make the Absolute Value Class negative?

Tags: java, math

If I were to print

`System.out.println(-Math.abs(-14));`

would it print -14 or would it disregard the negative sign on the outside of the Math.abs code?

Comment: why ask here when you can easily try it out?  Part of the fun is experimenting...

Comment: Easy enough to try. But I'm not sure why you'd expect anything *other* than `-14`: a function only operates on the parameters passed to it (ignoring horrible side-effect-laden functions), not the code surrounding the call.

Answer (score 1):

You will get -14. Please go try your code first to see its behaviour